# Multiple index search and PIT index ID reuse

Tags: elasticsearch

I’m planning to search multiple different sets of [multiple indices at once](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multiple-indices.html). I’d also like to use `search_after` with point-in-time indices for deep pagination. I’ve got some general questions about how/if PIT works in this scenario.

1. Calling the `_pit` endpoint with multiple indices works fine, but I’m not sure exactly how it works - is the PIT index coupled to the comma-separated set of indices I pass in my call to `_pit` (e.g. `/index-1,index-2/_pit?keep_alive=15m` will open a PIT id usable with any search where I want results from `index-1,index-2` )? Also, will the implicit `_shard_doc` tiebreaking work when creating a multi-index PIT index?
2. The [guidance on the elastic blog here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/get-a-consistent-view-of-your-data-over-time-with-the-elasticsearch-point-in-time-reader) re: having a background process create a PIT for use with all search requests (rather than creating one on each search request) seems to contradict the [PIT docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/point-in-time-api.html#:%7E:text=The%20open%20point%20in%20time%20request%20and%20each%20subsequent%20search%20request%20can%20return%20different%20id%3B%20thus%20always%20use%20the%20most%20recently%20received%20id%20for%20the%20next%20search%20request) which state the following — I must be misunderstanding one of these statements?

> The open point in time request and each subsequent search request can return different id; thus always use the most recently received id for the next search request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually found answers (with the help of a co-worker).

1. Multi-index PIT indices [are supported](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/86301#:%7E:text=Tested%20and%20confirmed%20that%20both%20opening%20a%20PIT%20and%20searching%20against%20a%20PIT%20works%20with%20multiple%20indices%2C%20even%20though%20it%20isn%27t%20explicitly%20mentioned%20in%20the%20docs.%20Also%20double%2Dchecked%20with%20the%20ES%20search%20team%20%26%20they%20confirmed%20that%20this%20is%20correct), though this is not reflected in the docs whatsoever at time of writing.

> Tested and confirmed that both opening a PIT and searching against a PIT works with multiple indices, even though it isn't explicitly mentioned in the docs. Also double-checked with the ES search team & they confirmed that this is correct.

2. Yes, PIT ids [are stable](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-i-trust-a-pit-id-once-it-has-been-replaced-by-a-new-pit-id/271054) for the requested `keep_alive` period (found in the context of a similar question on sharding).

> The answer to your question is yes, that the guarantee of PIT – a certain point of time in the index, regardless of what copies of shards are being used internally. If we can't find this point of time any more, an error of "no search context found" will be returned.
> But as I said in the previous answer, currently we always return the same PIT id even if we end up using different shard copies.